# How to make weback sass loader work efficiently in Angular application when number of line are too much in compiled css file from scss?

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass, webpack-dev-server

I am writing an utilities class in scss which compiles into gigantic css file which results  in to slow down or sometimes even stop my Angular application. Can anyone suggests me How can I handle this in webpack?

This is my scss which generate a gigantic css file

```
// margin and padding for all directions
@for $top from 0 through 100 {
    @for $right from 0 through 100 {
        @for $bottom from 0 through 100 {
            @for $left from 0 through 100 {
                .p-#{$top}-#{$right}-#{$bottom}-#{$left} {
                    padding: #{$top}px #{$right}px #{$bottom}px #{$left}px;
                }

                .m-#{$top}-#{$right}-#{$bottom}-#{$left} {
                    margin: #{$top}px #{$right}px #{$bottom}px #{$left}px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code will create this gigantic css file please refer any online scss to css converter

```
https://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/
```

Here is my webpack file code which is handling scss loader.

```
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PurgeCSS package which will removed the unused css from your css file after your application build.

Install PurgeCSS package.

```
npm install purgecss
```

Then add below command in your package.json file

```
"postbuild": "npm run purgecss",
"purgecss": "purgecss --css dist/*.css --content dist/index.html dist/*.js -o dist/"
```

Tailwind CSS uses this library to do the exact thing as it is also a utility based library.

Note:- Please note this will not work in development mode. In development mode there is no css file generate as output. css is handled in memory so this will not work in development mode.

Reference:-
https://purgecss.com/

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the thing is my webpack dev server is not even able to convert this into css which leads to memory full issue and when I reduce the loop from 100 to 20 or 10 may be then it compiles perfectly fine and application responds very slow which can be solved with the solution you provided.

Comment: I have update the answer, please check. There is no way possible to handle your use case in developement mode.